# Mini-VCI J2534 cable question

Tags: obd-ii

I purchased a mini-vci j2534 and I cannot get it to work with any of the ODBii software I have. I cannot read a honda, nor 2 chevy's. Is this cable ONLY for toyota programming software? I do have a new toyota and have not put it on that car since it is perfect.

Did I get the wrong cable to read OBDii's and reset codes?

Thank you in advance.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

**tl dr:** These devices are for Toyota only

The J2534 is supposed to be a "universal gateway" device providing a means by which to pass data regardless of the protocol used on the vehicle. Of all the products using this, they all say "Toyota Only". You should be able to plug it into your Toyota to get communications only (without changing anything) to ensure the cable is working correctly. This of course depends on the firmware version you currently have on the device. Only the newest firmware has the ability to read newer Toyotas. The older firmware is only good to about 2004 vehicles and earlier. All of this comes from [these questions and answers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D6BA082) posted on Amazon.com about the device.

Comment: I dont know what firmware I have on it. I have read and read, still cannot figure it out how to put firmware on it. I have been trying to read my old chevy and my wifes Honda Civic with this cable. From your this cable is a Toyota only cable and will NOT do generic OBD ii protocol. Is this correct?

Thank you for your pior and further response.

Mike

Comment: @Mike - I can give you better advice if you put the make/model of exactly what you are using and the specifics of the software. A link to the product would even be better.

Comment: It was a Mini-VCI J2534 cable I got off ebay. There is no name for the brand. It has clear case and clear usb cable.

Comment: @Mike - Would you have a link?

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/222121988166